# Как сделать правильную ассемблерную вставку

Tags: c++, c, ассемблер, gcc

Хочу попрактиковаться с ассемблерными вставками. Хотел написать код для вычисления суммы чисел от 1 до n, реализуя это на ассемблере. Однако пока не смог скомпилировать даже простой код записывающий в sum значение n. Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumN(int n)
{
    // calculate 1+2+...+n
    int sum;
    __asm__(
        "mov %1, %eax\n\t"
        "mov %eax, %0\n\t"
        :"=d"(sum)
        :"c"(n)
        :"%eax");
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        printf("n: %d sum(n): %d\n",i,sumN(i) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Однако компилятор g++ выдает ошибку

> main.cpp:11:11: error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after
>   %-letter                                                :"%eax");
>   ^
>   main.cpp:11:11: error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after
>   %-letter.

Думал что проблема в том что я не указал все регистры, которые я использую, поэтому немного переписал код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumN(int n)
{
    // calculate 1+2+...+n
    int sum;
    __asm__(
        "mov %1, %eax\n\t"
        "mov %eax, %0\n\t"
        :"=d"(sum)
        :"c"(n)
        :"%eax","%edx","%ecx");
    return sum;
}
int main()
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        printf("n: %d sum(n): %d\n",i,sumN(i) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Однако и такой код не компилируется, gcc выдает ошибку

> main.cpp:11:25: error: ‘asm’ operand has impossible constraints
>   :"%eax","%edx","%ecx");

Подскажите, в чем ошибка и как ее исправить?
P.S. руководствовался вот этой [статьей](http://asmcourse.cs.msu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gcc-inline-asm.pdf)

Comment: в статье было переключение на ителовский синтаксис

Answer (score 2):

В самом ассемблерном коде надо знак `%` экранировать, т.е. писать `%%eax`, а вот в clobber-списке, наоборот, знак `%` необязателен.

```
int sumN(int n)
{
    // calculate 1+2+...+n
    int sum;
    __asm__(
        "mov %1, %%eax\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
        :"=d"(sum)
        :"c"(n)
        :"eax");
    return sum;
}

...

$ gcc test.c -m32 -o test
$ ./test

n: 1 sum(n): 1
...
n: 99 sum(n): 99
```

Кстати, учтите,что про компиляции под x86-64, запись в eax обнуляет старшие биты rax. Это надо будет отразить в clobber-списке.